# forwardingSMTPaddress empty after remove and reassign O365 license

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

After a license clean up in O365, removing mail licenses of the inactive mailboxes  some incidents raised...

Looks like forwardingSMTPaddress parameter gets cleared/deleted after license removal and reassignation. I replicated the issue to check this behavior and is true.

So now I don't know if the reenabled mailboxes had a forward set up before the clean up.

Is there any way to recover this addresses, or at least any ideas to try ?

Many thanks

Comment: You could use the message tracking logs to identify the mailboxes and the forwarding destination address. Ugly, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Audit reports allow you to track any `set-`/`add-`/`remove-` actions against an object.  Not sure if you will be able to capture the information you want, though.  It would seem that it is the action of removing the license (deprovision mailbox) that is clearing the value.